# Error in How Are Survey Respondents Engaging on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, survey-2017

[Developer Survey Results 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=hero&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2017&utm_content=hero-ind-ques)

[image]

This should read 24% of all respondents or approx ?% who have accounts.

Comment: To me it looks like 77.4% of the respondents have an account and 24.1% have created a cv which would mean about 1/3 of people with an account have created a cv as well. Also the link you provided does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out -- we'll be pushing a correction soon so this will now read "Of those who do have accounts, 31% have tried...."